# Cannot take ownership of a folder I created even as admin

Tags: windows

I created a folder on Windows 10, then deleted it, for whatever reason some glitch happens, it reappears and I cannot gain access to it. I cannot even take ownership of it http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2014/01/folder-access-denied-delete-folder-windows/#.VpwfvSrhDqM as I do have no way to do so :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using take ownership reg file.